# elif statement name checker

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

i am new to python and running into something super silly. While trying to run an elif statement i am getting some errors. not sure what is it that I am doing wrong.

```
if name == 'Alice':
       print('Hi Alice!)
    elif age < 12:
         print('You are not Alice, kiddo.')
```

When I run this in terminal I get the error.

```
NameError: name 'Alice' is not defined
```

I know that I can *define* name at the top on the lines

```
name = input('What is your name: ')
```

So that it will ask me for the name and it is defined as well.

But I enter the name != Alice say Alan. It throws this error

```
NameError: name 'age' is not defined
```

I want the **elif** clause to execute immeditely if age < 12 is True and name == 'Alice' is False. Not sure where am i going wrong.

Comment: If the only `input` call you're executing is to get the user's name, then how is the program supposed to know what the user's age is? If you actually have an `input` call for both name and age, please include that in your [mcve].

Comment: Apart from specific answers, using an editor with syntax highlighting / language-aware formatting would help you spot those issues earlier. Have a look at using idle / pycharm / vscode / other options.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Answer (score 3):

I assume the incorrect indentation (`elif` should be on the same level as `if`) arose from pasting into SO. Other than that, you're missing a closing quote in your print function. Also, define `age` somewhere so that the `NameError` won't occur.

This code runs, although you probably want age as an input too:

```
name = input('What is your name: ')
age = 11

if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hi Alice!')
elif age < 12:
    print('You are not Alice, kiddo.')
```